# SoundCloud Embedding in Static HTML Website

Tags: html, iframe, soundcloud

I wanted to Purchase a server to host a site and i am embedding SoundCloud in the site i want to that as youtube embedding uses youtube bandwidth and not the hosting website space. so similarly does soundcloud uses the bandwidth of the hosting site or its own bandwidth after embedding the soundcloud

Below is the iframe for Soundcloud

```
<iframe width="100%" height="800" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/users/23397058&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false&amp;visual=true"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

The media is stored on SoundCloud’s servers and the browser fetches it from there.